# How to pass a list of gene ids to url?

Tags: python, biopython

I'm trying to pass a list of gene ids to url. `gl` stores a list of gene ids. I need `"?term="` to iterate over the elements in the list and perform the function defined.

```
import re
import urllib2

def sr():
    gl = [6323,6513]

    # need to pass the list gl here:
    s = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term=','r')

    h = s.read()
    s.close()
    acc = re.search('gi=(.+?)&amp',h)
    if acc:
            ac = acc.group(1)
            f = open("E:/t.txt", "w")
            f.write(ac);
            f.close()
```

Comment: Have you looked at the NCBI Entrez Utilities, their official API for doing searches and downloaded data? Biopython has a `Bio.Entrez` module designed to help use this.

Comment: I mention in my answer below how to use a for loop to iterate over the answers. But there are more problems in your code, including that using `re.search` will not look through the file handle (you'd have to have a loop to do that)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive I understand what you're looking for, but perhaps [`urllib.urlencode`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) is what you're looking for? `urlencode` will generate a query string. You can pass this, along with the base URL to [`urllib.urlopen`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen).

I'm assuming the values for `term` are supposed to be comma-delimited?

```py
gl = [6323,6513]
params = urllib.urlencode({"term": ','.join(map(str, gl))})
s urllib.urlopen('http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/', params)
```

---

As Peter Cock mentioned in the comments, you're better off using Entrez, NCBI's official API ([guide here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25501/)). [`Bio.Entrez`](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Entrez-module.html) provides a nice interface.

Comment: concept is simple i need to get nucleotide ids for the specified gene ids, you can find nucleotide id in gene id html page source code eg;http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term=6323, search for "gi" it stores the nucleotide id. Above code works if only 1 gene id is given i need to extract for a list of gene ids

Comment: Before posting this question i went through Ncbi eutils and Bio.Entrez, we can find a list of gene ids related to a specific nucleotide id but the reverse is not possible, coz each gene has a start position and position which we have to specify here:

Comment: Thanq David Robinson for your correction in the code, it works with the changes made as you specified but i have to use loop to seperate each extraction process for each gene id in the list